# Can I transplant an iPhone 6 logic board?

Tags: iphone, hardware

I was wondering if it would be possible to transplant my broken iPhone 6's working logic board to a working iPhone 6, and if the memory would transfer with the logic board? Any feedback would be helpful.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, it doesn't function well for tutorial or 'how to' questions.

Comment: I'm sure it would be a whole lot simpler to just restore to the new phone. Can we assume you failed to back it up & now cannot?

Comment: @fsb i diddnt ask how to do it, i asked if it would be possible.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes you can assume that

Comment: Anything is possible.  As it's currently written, this question appears to be overly broad and theoretical.  What have you done already to answer this question?